# Windows 7 x64 CD to MP3 ripper

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ripping

I'm trying to find a good, simple CD-to-MP3 ripper to copy my physical CD's to my computer's hard disk.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional x64 - and that appears to be a major problem. All the "usual" free- and shareware tools I've tried (CD-to-MP3, Visual MP3 and quite a few more) seem to have trouble with either 64-bit Windows, or with my HP CD/DVD built into my HP Compaq Elite 8100 machine.

Does anyone have any good recommendations? I don't want to install a monster like iTunes - something really clean, small, simple would be fine. Free- or Shareware - if it works reliably and with good quality output, I'll be **happy** to register!

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: Please don't create three useless tags at once. We already have enough on this site -- so make use of those that are more popular. Thanks!

Comment: @slhck: that comment looks funny when you look at the current 3 tags: windows-7, 64-bit, and ripping. (yes, I did see the original question & its' 3 useless tags)

Comment: So umm... Any answer you like yet, marc_s

Comment: related: [Best Audio bitrate/encoding?](http://superuser.com/q/112329/494)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm on Windows 7 x64 as well.  I've used [CDex](http://cdexos.sourceforge.net/) for years. Up until recently there wasn't even an installer, just a zip package.

Comment: CDex is pretty ligheweight and works really well, I've used it for years.  If you need something to try to read scratched CDs accurately also try EAC - http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/.

Comment: Looks like a really small, focused and well executed program - thanks for the hint! Testing as I type ....

Answer (score 4):

Anything wrong with Windows Media Player?

Comment: I've always used Media Player too.

Comment: Seems pretty ugly, clunky, and not very intuitive to use as a CD ripper, quite honestly ....

Comment: Mind giving more details as to why it's ugly or clunky, or not intuitive? It downloads the album information and album art automatically for you as well, and adds the media to your library

Comment: Well, I tried to configure it to put the resulting MP3 into **my** directory structure (not the usual "My Music" or whatever), and I tried to tell it to use subdirectories for artist and album - couldn't do it. In the end, when trying it out - WMP did use that convention - but it wasn't "visible" or discoverable in the UI. What if I'd like to change it?? I can define the resulting MP3 file name - but I cannot seem to define where exactly to store the output.... also, the whole UI feels clunky and overloaded and way too complicated ......

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to list the requirements you are looking for... Might get better answers

Answer (score 1):

Another solution maybe [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Exact Audio Copy](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/), which has a plethora of options for a super user.

Others have mentioned EAC, but I think it deserves an answer in its own right, so it can be commented on, and voted for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Zune player will do this. It's lightweight and pretty easy to use. Plus, the UI is really well designed.

Answer (score 0):

[Easy CD-DA Extractor](http://www.poikosoft.com/) is [compatible with 32-bit and 64-bit Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Software&p=Easy%20CD-DA%20Extractor%20Professional&v=Poikosoft&uid=12&l=en&pf=1&pi=8&c=Music%20&%20MP3&sc=CD/DVD%20Utilities&os=64-bit)

[EAC](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/en/) seems to [can work on Win7 x64](http://www.digital-inn.de/exact-audio-copy-english/40402-using-eac-windows-7-64-bit.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/). It's been a while since I've used it (it's Windows only, or was at least), but I remember it having more options than any sane person would ever need and shockingly light-weight. [Here's a ripping walkthrough for it.](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Ripping_CDs_with_Foobar2000)

[It seems](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Converter) you need to install [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) separately to encode to mp3. You probably want to [get that here](http://www.rarewares.org/mp3-lame-bundle.php), as the LAME peoples are somewhat anal about distributing binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the common 'audiophile' answer to that question is dBpoweramp (or EAC which has already been mentionned). There is a free version and the pay-version has profiles you setup once and use ever after. It can rip many formats in parallel (ie. flac and mp3 simultaneously).

Until now I've also been using CDex.